# Add a Stationary Picture Frame to the Circumference of a Rotating Animation

Tags: animation, camera

CONTEXT: I'm building an animation where the camera is rotating along a circular path around an animated looping object.

I would like to add a picture frame, like you would find in a museum, around the animation. Basically the frame would stand still, like it's attached to the wall, and the animation would move inside.

I'm relatively new to Blender and I can't figure this one out. Not sure if I can attach a picture frame mesh to the camera itself, add it after rendering, or maybe this something I should add a frame in photoshop later.

Happy to provide more details and thanks in advance ✌

Comment: just parent your frame to your camera - that's all

Comment: Ok thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new project, delete everything, and add a *Bezier Circle*:

[image: Circ1]

Scale the circle up to your liking (I did 10x) and apply scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* (this may not be necessary for a curve circle, but it is a good practice when scaling in *Object Mode*):

[image: Circ2]

Add a Camera to the scene, access the transform menu with <kbd>N</kbd>, and change the rotation to (X,Y,Z) 90, 0, -90.

[image: Circ3]

Add a *Constraint* to the Camera, select the *Bezier Circle* as your target object, make sure to select "Follow Curve", and also remember to animate the path. This will make your camera follow the circle while pointing at the center.

[image: Circ4]

Add your frame, and parent it to the camera with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> - select parent, keep transform. The frame will now rotate with your camera.

[image: Circ5]

You place your animation in the center of the frame, and parent it to the camera in the same way.

Comment: Thank you this is very very helpful!!